# Using repository, service design pattern in laravel

Tags: laravel, design-patterns

I’m trying to use repository, service design patterns but stuck on the concept of these patterns and I'm sure that I'm not understanding these patterns.

For example I have User(id, name, etc) model and made interface, repository, service, controller like below.

```
/**
* user repository interface
* App\Repositories\Interfaces\IUserRepo.php
*/
interface IUserRepo
{
    public function getAllUsers();
}

/**
* user repository
* App\Repositories\UserRepository.php
*/
class UserRepository implements IUserRepo
{
    protected User $userModel;
    
    public function __construct(User $userModel)
    {
        $this->userModel = $userModel;
    }
    
    public function getAllUsers()
    {
        return $this->userModel->get();
    }
}

/**
* user service
* App\Services\UserService.php
*/
class UserService
{
    protected UserRepository $userRepository;
    
    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }
    
    public function userList()
    {
        return $this->userRepository->getAllUsers();
    }
}

/**
* user controller
* App\Http\Controllers\UserController.php
*/
class UserController
{
    protected UserService $userService;
    
    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }
    
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $users = $this->userService->userList();
        
        return response()->json(['users' => $users]);
    }
}
```

Is it correct to add it like this every time when I need to join some tables?

```
interface IUserRepo
{
    public function getAllUsers();
    
    public function getAllUsersWithType();
    
    public function getAllUsersWithStatus();
    
    public function getAllUsersWithTypeAndStatus();
}
```

I have searched but can't find about joins for list.. help me

Comment: You SHOULD NOT use repository pattern in laravel

Comment: @Maksim thanks but can you give me some more details why not to use??

Comment: there is nothing that says you can not use this pattern with Eloquent (Active Record Models) ... it is just that Active Record Models already act as a record and a repository basically ... so the concept of abstracting the database functionality to the repository for a single point of responsibility is just conceptual as there is nothing stopping the developer from directly using the model to interact with the database

Comment: Implementing some similiar with this one at my repo https://github.com/WailanTirajoh/Laravel-Hotel

Abstraction wont add much value if you doesnt need to get data from more than 1 place (eg: Other API services & DB). It will just increase unnecessary complexity.